# Filling select option doesn't work with selectpicker class

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a bootstrap Selectpicker controle, I want to fill it with Javascript, the code works fine with simple Select input, but when I add `class="selectpicker"` it doesn't work anymore

Here is my code :
HTML

```
<select id="hotspotList" class="selectpicker show-menu-arrow form-control">
</select>
```

Javascript

```
var select = document.getElementById("hotspotList");
var options = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "12"];
for(var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
    var opt = options[i];
    var el = document.createElement("option");
    el.textContent = opt;
    el.value = opt;
    select.appendChild(el);
}
```

Comment: It is working in jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/h3esryun/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Use `refresh()`, To programmatically update a select with JavaScript, first manipulate the select, then use the refresh method to update the UI to match the new state. This is necessary when removing or adding options, or when disabling/enabling a select via JavaScript. Refer https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/

```
 $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');
```

Comment: Thank you,  you saved my day :)

Comment: I won't mind if you accept and upvote :) **Happy coding**

Answer (score 0):

**Updated:**

Just **Enable** Bootstrap - Select via JavaScript like:

```
$('#hotspotList').selectpicker('refresh');
```

Comment: It didn't work, this works :  $('#hotspotList').selectpicker('refresh');

Answer (score 0):

**`$('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');`** **will work.**

```js
function addMore(){
var select = document.getElementById("hotspotList");
var options = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "12"];
for(var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
    var opt = options[i];
    var el = document.createElement("option");
    el.textContent = opt;
    el.value = opt;
    select.appendChild(el);
}
    
   
$(".selectpicker").selectpicker('refresh');
    
}


$(document).ready(function(){
$(".selectpicker").selectpicker();
})
```

```css
@import url('http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.7.5/css/bootstrap-select.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.7.5/js/bootstrap-select.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.1.0/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<select class="selectpicker" id="hotspotList">
  <option>Mustard</option>
  <option>Ketchup</option>
  <option>Barbecue</option>
</select>

<button onclick="addMore()"> addMore !</button>
```